# My own OBD2 "server"

Tags: obd-ii

I need to translate the rs232 stream from my [ECU](https://www.race-technology.com/wiki/index.php/ECUType/CanemsECU) to OBD2 compliant messages. I suppose I will have to put a computer after rs232 connector that will translate (parse and transform) messages so that OBD2 diagnostic tools will be able to request and read them.

I am absolute beginner in this topic, so I wanted to start just to generate some messages that will be consumed by OBDII diagnostic tools. For that I am planning to buy [USB<->OBD2 cable](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/314773367115?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20201210111314%26meid%3Debd281e4a3bb422eb09dcfff2d880ccb%26pid%3D101195%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D373222449769%26itm%3D314773367115%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D4429486%26algv%3DSimplAMLv11WebTrimmedV3MskuWithLambda85KnnRecallV1V2V4ItemNrtInQueryAndCassiniVisualRankerAndBertRecallWithVMEV3CPCAutoWithCassiniEmbRecallManual%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p4429486.c101195.m1851&itmprp=cksum%3A314773367115ebd281e4a3bb422eb09dcfff2d880ccb%7Cenc%3AAQAIAAABcKAO6YGL7I8ZT6VFWcHmDuKm898HGH9cNRsnG%252Fep%252BzC3UPHwPSmfpPq3b41cHxht%252FCiwo5DdbtiFsRNqRhAUlK8x2MLrmISu5pnzSn%252FhiW3P7y%252BKcxGllTjL%252BG3bIP4k8fGgzCrVY1dxXbjuBFp3vefxTYgjBXBRUWQBgGciI%252FuQ5Mjsfl%252B%252FiL4cv70dT88jK8fr9ZLaCQM%252FwnkZpIpMtVzR2qcAxX%252BsFX0C8XFiZKElqJ9oY7lHPwSwfiukS90wHPDzRcQjBgwSm%252B%252BIdGyKNN%252Bx44bc381qboagxHXAU8VxxDEG6KalP%252Faoo6DNPjWsY4U4X8Nvf%252FaYLYHFJQWbCJ9PgQME8BSSgjU%252B6c5QAxGdgUfTv4dNxjOfGkWFxen2z8KPk77Nc8Y7N3q0r0N62Dyzy%252FDT4NSAGXVdoZCgfmAafgcPqX%252FTcBJ1K4mQj3oLCUXsMnrgnP9j%252BcYYexb6x2sLQwM6ECAIXVgy3GgkF%252BBe%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A4429486&itmmeta=01HRN77PFYJ0X94SF15Y6R1Q6H).

I found out that the vast majority of OBD libraries are designed to send a request and process the result from OBDII. Are there any libraries that can help to develop custom OBD2 "server" that will listen to requests and provide results? Can you draft a simple program that will generate VIN, manufacturer name and some engine properties when the diagnostic OBD2 system will be connected and request these?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! We've had questions like this in the past and they don't do very well, as in they are rarely answered. I think most people who frequent here are more about the mechanical side of things. Most OBDII questions are related to how OBDII can tell us what's wrong with the vehicle. While your question is definitely not off topic, I just thought I'd warn you. If you do happen to find an answer to your question, please feel free to post the answer so we can have some clues as to what's going on.

Comment: And additionally to Paulster's comment, manufacturers keep much of their proprietary intellectual property well protected, so you may find that not all the info is available in any case.